# Android Client TCP socket

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I'm implementing a Android client and desktop server application. In Client, i extends a Thread class for sending and receiveing TCP messages. It will handle my messages and do something due to the message's meaning. But the messages doesnot come from server to the client..It doesnot appear in my thread bufferedreader. 
I'm new at android. Where did i miss a point?
Can my thread not working in the background?

```
public class ConnectionHandler extends Thread {

private Socket mySocket;
public static BufferedReader in;
public static PrintWriter out;

private Login login;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket,Login login) throws IOException{
    mySocket = socket;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream()));
    this.login = login;
}

public static void writeToOut(String msg){
    out.write(msg);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

public static void LoginMessage1ToOut(String emailField,String passField){
    String msg = "1;"+emailField+";"+passField+";";
    Log.d("LoginMsg1",msg);
    writeToOut(msg);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try{
        while(true){
            String cameString = in.readLine();
            String[] tokens = cameString.split(";");
            Log.d("*msg",cameString);
            if(tokens[0].equals("2")){
                if(tokens[1].equals("positive")){
                    login.enterIn();
                }else{
                    login.somethingWrong("Inputs doesnot match.Please re-type.");
                }
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception es){}
}
}
```

This thread class created with login activity.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be:

```
  while (true) {
    try {
     String cameString = in.readLine(); //This line maybe throw an error like timeout
         //check not null
         if(cameString != null){

            String[] tokens = cameString.split(";");
            Log.d("*msg",cameString);
            if(tokens[0].equals("2")){
                if(tokens[1].equals("positive")){
                   login.enterIn();
             }else{
                login.somethingWrong("Inputs doesnot match.Please re-type.");
            }
           }
         } 

} catch (Exception e) {
       //Ignore the error
}
}
```

Comment: please, add some description of what your code does.